# Why is new acoustic texture cracking?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, paint, popcorn

I am having ceiling repairs done in my house after a water leak from the roof. The bathroom repairs are not going well. The first time they scraped off the old popcorn and put new popcorn on it didn't stick.

They scraped it all off being sure to gouge the heck out of the drywall in the process then put a primer down before adding the popcorn. This time it stuck better but is cracking all over the place. It looks like an old oil painting.

Does anyone know what is causing this? I suspected they are spraying too thick to compensate for all the damage they caused scraping the ceiling. My son's room came out fine so far other then the gouges which they say I am being too picky.

Here are [some pictures](https://imgur.com/gallery/M6i7R7a).

[image]

Comment: Looks like they can't get the spray volume correct and the mix is too wet.

Comment: The mixture is definitely too wet.  If they were any good, they would know that on the first bit of application.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That is what I told them on the first application. It seemed way too runny. But the second application was in a 5 gallon bucket. I think it was Sherwin-Williams 400. Is that premixed?

Comment: That would explain why my son's room came out fine. The mix has a time to dry and they did his room last.

Comment: I talked to them and they are blaming the drywall still. They won't acknowledge the mix was too wet. What are your thoughts on "bad drywall"?

Comment: If "they" put up the drywall, it's still on them, no? If someone else did the drywall, then an [edit] to indicate that might help.

Comment: It was the original drywall in the house.